# Is there any way to handle class names with index numbers in css?

Tags: css

I want to give same style in CSS to many tables at the same time. Each table has a class name such as "table1", "table2"...

```
.table1 th.column-1,
.table2 th.column-1,
.table3 th.column-1,
...
```

I know it's easy to handle it if I can enclose each table with an outer div with an identical ID or class name. Is there any way to handle it without adding an outer div?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do not understand. Why don't you give all tables the class `.table`? Or any other class with the same name.

Comment: Instead of using incremented class names for your table, all you need to do is assign a common class to all of them and the tables which has unique styles can be defined separately.

Comment: @JLow. Thanks for your comment. It's a sample and it's about tables which are automatically generated by an application.

Comment: @Peter You're welcome. If it is not in your hands the other answers are fine. If you have the possibility I would try to tell this application to add the same class to all tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give regular expressions for CSS Selectors. All classes that start with `table`:

```
table[class^="table"]
```

So your CSS code becomes:

```
table[class^="table"] {
    /* All the Rules */
}
```

These are called attribute selectors. You can find more info about them at [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that it's possible to use regular expressions in CSS. Thanks for the useful link too

Answer (score 3):

You can do this to your css selector :

```
table[class^="table"] {
    //your code
}
```

This will check for table tags that have a class that begins with `table`

Answer (score 0):

Try `*[class^="table"] {color:red;}`